# React class component rendering twice

Tags: reactjs, render

I have created a class component as in the code.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import Home from "./components/home";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Home />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

home.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Home extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    console.log("Render Home");
    return <h1>Home</h1>;
  }
}

export default Home;
```

If I change it the Home to a functional component then it render only once.
But why is class component rendering twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) regarding Strict Mode:

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
> - Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
> - Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

Fortunately, this only applies to *development mode*, so you won't have this double-rendering in production.

Comment: Okay, But even in the development mode double rendering messes my code. Is there a way to avoid this trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Try without strict mode:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Home />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```